# Python script can be run on console but cannot run after double-click the .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python code below to pronounce the current year, month, day and weekday from speaker in Cantonese(Chinese).

Below code can be run and pronounce clearly if run on python console(here I use python 3.7, windows 10)

However, Below code cannot run if double-click the .py file.

Any thoughts?

```html
import requests
import os
import datetime
def TTS(text, speed, lan, per):
    """粤语-音色：标准音
    """
    convertTable = {
        '粤语': ('CTE', {'标准音': 0
        })
    }
    data = {
        'tex': text,
        'spd': speed,
        'lan': convertTable[lan][0],
        'per': convertTable[lan][1][per],
        'ctp': 1,
        'cuid': 'baike',
        'ie': 'UTF-8',
        'pdt': 301,
        'vol': 9,
        'rate': 32
    }
    result = requests.get('https://tts.baidu.com/text2audio', params=data)
    try:
        result.json()
    except:
        return result.content
    else:
        raise ValueError

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt=datetime.datetime.now()
    y=str(dt)[:4]
    if str(dt)[5:6]=="0":
        m=str(dt)[6:7]
    else:
        m=str(dt)[5:7]
    if str(dt)[8:9]=="0":
        d=str(dt)[9:10]
    else:
        d=str(dt)[8:10]
    numbers={
        1:"星期一",
        2:"星期二",
        3:"星期三",
        4:"星期四",
        5:"星期五",
        6:"星期六",
        0:"星期日"
    }
    TextToSpeak=y+"年"+m+"月"+d+"日"+numbers.get(int(dt.strftime("%w")),"None")
    print(TextToSpeak)
    try:
        bindata = TTS(TextToSpeak, 5, '粤语', '标准音')
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        with open('date.mp3', 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(bindata)
        os.startfile('date.mp3')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Only for Windows

If when double clicking the .py it seems like a Window opens and closes quickly, then your file is really executed but it is so quick that you don't even have the time to see the possible errors. In order to test if it really works write a .py with this code:

```py
text_file = open("test.txt","w")
text_file.write("Hello World!")
text_file.close()
```

Try to run and if a test.txt is created, the script was indeed executed.

### Run on double click

You could possibly try these steps:

1- Just Right Click the script file and go to properties.

2- Select the option ‘Opens with:’ in General tab, and select the python from list, if its not available then browse to the installation directory of python and select the python.exe from there.

3- Now when you double click on the file it will run automatically.

#### If it still doesn't work

In case this still doesn't work you should open your favorite text editor and write this script:

```
ECHO ON
SET PATH=<C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\>
python <you_program>.py
PAUSE
```

Of course you should change the path with the corresponding one on your computer.
Once you have written your script you have to save it as a **Batch file**, for example run.bat

This time try to double click the run.bat

Comment: Sorry, no luck.. Can you run it by double click?

Comment: I just updated the solution in case the first one wasn't working to you :D

Comment: I know somewhere is not right. Double clicking should run the .py file but don't know how

Comment: Does it seem like a window opens and closes quickly? If yes, your program executes. Read here: [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20come%20when%20I%20double%20click%20on%20a%20.py%20a%20black%20thing%20flashes%20and%20then%20disappears%3F%20And%20what/where%20exactly%20is%20the%20%27Python%20Interpreter%27%3F)

Comment: To test if it really runs do this: 
`text_file = open("test.txt","w")
text_file.write("Hello World!")
text_file.close()`
It should create you a test.txt. If the text file is there, then your previous code doesn't run correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is because the .py file is really a bunch of plain text.
The easiest way is to write a .bat script that calls the python script.

So for example, if you had a file called, run.bat
You can have the line:
`python /path/to/python/file`

And by double-clicking the .bat file, it will return the python script in a console.

Comment: I really want to run the .py with simply double clicking.. Any thoughts

Comment: Don't think that would work in windows.
In Linux yes if you use a shebang, but as far as I know, windows does not support this. Or even if you could work, it would not be supported by default.
Generally people covert their script into an executable (.exe) but then you will run into a "this isn't a verified software issue". 
I'd say best bet is to go down the batch file option.